# sbt new not a valid command

Tags: scala, sbt

I am going through a coursera course and as explained, I am trying to create a new sbt project using the below command:

```
sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

In a Windows machine. I have sbt 0.13.8 installed. When executing the command it is giving the below error.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Set current project to workspaces (in build file:/D:/software%20materials%20workspaces/WorkSpaces/)
[error] Not a valid command: new (similar: set)
[error] Not a valid project ID: new
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: new (similar: name, run, runner)
[error] new
[error]    ^
```

I am not able to understand what the problem is. Help me out in understanding and solving this problem

Comment: `sbt new` was added fairly recently; sbt 0.13.8 is pretty old. Try the latest version (at the moment, 0.13.15).

Comment: Thanks for the help.Any direct command to upgrade from 0.13.8 to 0.13.15 or similar from command line?

Comment: I am currently installing sbt 0.13.15 using windows installer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Seth. It looks like the first version to include new is 0.13.13. I just came across this in creating new apps with more recent versions of the Scala Play framework (ex: 2.5). The github templating command line, giter8, is called via sbt new like this:

```
sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ben. I have installed the latest sbt(0.13.15) using .msi windows installer. But when i tried to do sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8. It started downloading some resources and in the update.log i am getting the below error. 
`no ivy file in cache for org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.15: tried C:\****\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-sbt\main\ivy-0.13.15.xml` 
and after this next line it is like `local: resource not reachable for org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.15: res=C:\****\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.15\ivys\ivy.xml` !

Comment: Don't know exactly what's wrong. The error message suggests that 13.15 is not using Ivy, or that ivy/maven cannot link up 13.15 with Ivy. You might try re-installing 13.15 anew, or perhaps clearing your Ivy/maven cache and trying after that (?). I wonder about your version of Ivy. But beyond that I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @ben I will try that

Comment: @Dileep I'd suggest accepting Ben's answer for this question, and then open a new question with the new problem you're having.

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys are awesome. I am still not able to solve the above-stated problem. Will open a new question. Tried to delete the folder C:\****\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\ and re-install sbt. Still, the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac I ran into a similar issue and fixed it by updating brew (used to install) then updating sbt:

```
brew update
brew upgrade sbt
```

First step was needed so the latest sbt could install. If whatever package manager you are using is out of date, it may result in the same problem. Not sure what Windows needs to install but this may help with others landing on this question.